# How to have conditional workflow execution in flyte?

Tags: python, flyte

I am currently using flyte for a project. In it, I have a number of workflows, A,B,C etc.
However, I recently identified a use case that requires me to change which workflow I run first, A1 or A2.

After learning you can't use if statements in a workflow due to

> Flytekit does not support Unary expressions or performing truth value
> testing

I determined that I probably needed to use dynamics since the execution is being determined at runtime.

So I tried something like:

```
#...Reference tasks are described up here...

@dynamic
def start_node_generator(should_use_a1):
    if should_use_a1:
        node_to_use = create_node(node_a1_reference_task)
        conditional_val=1
        return conditional_val, node_to_use
    else:
        node_to_use = create_node(node_a2_reference_task).with_overrides(name="spam")
        conditional_val=node_to_use.o1
        return conditional_val, node_to_use
        
@workflow
def main_workflow(should_use_a1):
    conditional_val, nodeA = start_node_generator(should_use_a1=should_use_a1)
    nodeB = create_node(nodeB_reference_task, conditional_val=conditional_val)
    nodeC = create_node(nodeC_reference_task)
    nodeA >> nodeB
    nodeB >> nodeC
```

However, I'm clearly thinking about this slightly wrong. You can't return Nodes out of either @tasks or @dynamics since they're not serializable.

How do you conditionally run A1 or A2 first, then the rest?

Comment: Meta comment, no idea if the [python] tag is correct here, since the workflow body is actually a DSL highly resembling python. I saw that other flyte questions included it so I did as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does `conditional` fits into your use case?

https://docs.flyte.org/projects/flytekit/en/latest/generated/flytekit.conditional.html#flytekit.conditional

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a workflow to be executed within the conditional. All examples I've seen have tasks embedded in those conditional() blocks. 

More specifically, they require a promise in the then() block. A workflow by itself is not a promise. But an output is; ie, my_workflow.o1. However, its unclear that this would ensure that the workflow executed.